# NHibernate lazy loading. Retrieve data on demand

Tags: nhibernate, lazy-loading

I have some class with associated list. I want this list not to be loaded when I retrieve the entity, but I want to have an opportunity to load this list later, outside the session in which I cought the entity.
Can NHibernate's lazy mechanism do this? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory you can implement your own IBytecodeProvider / ProxyFactory and do whatever you want. But that's quite complex, so you'll want to stick to regular NHibernate usage, which dictates that **lazy loading requires an active session**. It can be the originating session or you can reattach an entity from a previous session using [ISession.Lock()](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-update-lock)

Answer (score 0):

From outside of the session, you will always get an exception when you access an not-yet loaded object.

There is a way to get your objects from a new session. What you want to do is known as "Remote Lazy Loading". See http://www.theserverside.com/news/1363571/Remote-Lazy-Loading-in-Hibernate